# Active Directory vs Sitecore Security Provider

Tags: active-directory, sitecore

We are beginning to implement Sitecore for our website at my company. We are in the midst of the discovery phase and evaluating Active Directory module. We have 40-50 users who will be using Sitecore and over a 100 users who will be using some customized applications on top of Sitecore.

The consultancy we hired are asking us to not go with Active Directory since only 40-50 users will be using it. I on the other hand think that using the Active Directory module would be useful in the long run.

Do you guys have any input? What is the recommended practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really comes down to how you want to govern your CMS users. The AD module bubbles up those users into the CMS as users and thus exposes them for login. You can even do the same with groups/units. The advantage here is that if a new person joins your org, if you add them to the OU or assign then to a group that has Sitecore access then they gain access to Sitecore.

On the flip side, if you want Sitecore to be it's own entity with its own user profiles and logins, it can do that in a silo without the AD connection

To the CMS, there is no difference where the users are actually authenticated because the provider you select is low level. So the ultimate decision would be more of a governance / IT / process decision as there's really no functional difference.

My recommendation for you is to come up with scenarios or use cases and think through each in both scenarios. Eg you hire 10 people that need author access. With the AD module you just assign them to the OU or group that inherits te author roles in Sitecore and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the Active Directory module a few times now and it works really well when you want to have users to be able to SSO into the authoring interface and manage your security access within Active Directory. You can also use it well for doing end-user SSO if you are building something like an Intranet application on Sitecore.

From a security management perspective, it becomes easier for the organization and also allows you to not worry about having to duplicate users between different environments (Dev, Test, Prod).

That being said, there is a performance overhead with using the Active Directory module that is not present if you use only the native Sitecore security provider. With your number of users, you probably won't see any difference, but with extremely large AD directories with complex group memberships you may run into performance issues if you are using indirect membership (i.e. groups within groups).

An example scenario:

1. Content item in Sitecore is secured to the role MyDomain\SuperAuthor
2. User A is directly a member of MyDomain\SuperAuthor
3. User B is a member of MyDomain\SuperUser
4. MyDomain\SuperUser group is a member of MyDomain\SuperAuthor

If you use the Sitecore security provider, resolving User B's access is very efficient. Sitecore is able to check the indirect membership quickly using the roles within the system.

If you use the Active Directory module, the indirect membership is disabled by default. Only User A would have access. If you change the configuration setting to enable indirect membership, the module will then allow User B to have access, however you will begin to see a slower performance for that scenario.

As I mentioned before, however, if Active Directory is not very complex as to what is being pulled into Sitecore, you should be fine and probably won't notice these performance impacts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think number of users should be the sole reason to decide on whether or not to integrate AD nor should it be because you may or may not need it in the long run. I would say integrate with AD because of its most obvious benefits

1. Single user name and password
2. Better security
3. Ease of maintenance

Although number of users becomes and important deciding factor when you need to create several thousand users and setup authorization for them.

The most common reason users are manually created and maintained in sitecore is when you need to create a handful of authors and approver accounts mostly for the marketing team. But if you foresee implementing membership or need to provide access and authorization based on an existing user and group policy then go for AD integration.